# Is that possible to monitor mysql in cloudwatch?

Tags: disk-space-utilization, memory-usage, amazon-cloudwatch

I have some server in EC2, In that i have configured memory/disk usage metric in cloudwatch it is showing overall usage but i want to check memory of particular path How to check that? Is that possible?